# How to declare a Set in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have following code

```
private readonly direction :any ={
    east : "1",
    west : "2"
}

private readonly validDirections:Set<Object>= new Set(Object.values(this.direction));
```

But typescript compiler shows an error saying 'Set' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
Also it shows 'values' does not exist in type Object Constructor

[image: 'Set' only refers to a type]
[image: values does not exist]

I am using typescript 2.1.5.

highlights from tsconfig.json:

```
 "target": "es6"
"lib": ["dom","es6","es7.object"],
```

What am i doing wrong here? How to solve this issue?

Comment: Try `"lib": ["dom","es2016","es2017.object"]` instead. I'm not sure what `Set` error is about.

Comment: adding es2017.object works

Answer (score 1):

You may need to fix your configuration like following:

```
"lib": ["dom","es2016","es2017.object"],
```